How to inject a value in graphql template string?
I'm trying to get list of orders based on the customer id, which was stored in localStorage. I want to inject this customer id to the graphql query.
I tried injecting the customer id into graphql template string using "useStaticQuery" hook but getting the following error
"BabelPluginRemoveGraphQLQueries: String interpolations are not allowed in graphql fragments.
Included fragments should be referenced as ...MyModule_foo."
import React from 'react';
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';

const OrderPage = (props) => {
  const customerId = "7a10c10f-4a26-4fc1-95fc-fb7ed678a4f8";

  const { allOrder } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query GetOrdersByCustomerId {
      allOrder(filter: {customerId: {eq: ${customerId}}}) {
        nodes {
          id
          lineItems {
            name {
              en_US
            }
            quantity
            totalPrice {
              centAmount
            }
          }
          billingAddress {
            firstName
            lastName
            streetName
            postalCode
            streetNumber
            city
            country
          }
          shippingAddress {
            city
            country
            firstName
            lastName
            postalCode
            streetName
            streetNumber
          }
          customerId
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  return (
    <Layout>
        <h1>Orders page</h1>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default OrderPage;


